# Is it possible to create a client-side work-space based app in react-native?

Tags: android, react-native

I want to create a client-side android app in react-native that has the following features:

- Upload Image/Videos from the device
- Insert and remove the description
- Store account details in a server
- Auto-login to google account

But I have no idea on what plugins I should use. Please recommend me the things I should do and their features as well as limitations.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, definitely, you can develop it using react-native

Solutions to your problem:

1. For Uploading Images/ Videos you can use [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) or [react-native-fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob)
2. For CRUD operations you can use your api calls using default **fetch API**
3. For login from google account you can use [react-native-google-signin](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin)